# Update icon returned by CSS

Tags: css, icons, gsp

In the application I am working on, we can add the following markup for the pictured result

```
      <span class="cell-inner-undefined">
        <span title='Not defined' class="status pl-undefined" ></span>
      </span>
```

[image]

Inside the relevant CSS we have the following:

```
.pl-undefined:before {
    content: "";
    color:#969696;
}
```

The item assigned to content looks like unicode. Instead of that I want to get the result of the following:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-stack-1x" style="color:blue" ></i>
      <i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-1x" style="color:red"></i>
</span>
```

How can I get the class 'pl-undefined' to return the FA icon generated above?

p.s: Adding the fa span in my page displays the desired icon, but I need it to be displayed using the class.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: Sorry, I can create a fiddle with the FA, but not sure how to transfer the unicode character.. Even in VI it just shows a square with F059 in.. According to online resources this isnt the icon I am looking at which is strange.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this clearly without knowing what all the css is for the `fa` classes but (probably) you could write your `.pl-undefined:before` to look like the first `i` and your `.pl-undefined:after` to look like the second `i` and you'll end up with the effect you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any other way of achieving this, other than adding a javascript which will find a `<span class="cell-inner-undefined">` and replace it with the fa CSS